# TypeORM: Could I custom column index name when I use @TableInheritance

Tags: typeorm

My Table:

```
@TableInheritance({ column: 'type' })
export abstract class Node extends Base {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  id!: number

  @Column({
    length: '64',
  })
  type!: string
}
```

When I synchronize the table, TypeORM will auto create index for `type` column named `"IDX_8b154b7bf6c0dc0551948d6994"`. How can I custom index name?